# Visual Studio Code stops tracking changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code often stops tracking my changes. I'm writing Angular apps, serving them locally during development with *ng serve*. This can easily happen a dozen times a day or more, regardless of the project I'm in. Restarting VSC resolves the issue and all GIT differences are then reflected again in the code editor and Source Control view.

I keep my VSC updated to the latest version, though this has been happening for well over a year. I'm finally just frustrated enough to ask if anyone else experienced this.

Comment: What OS do you run ? your code is on a regular file system (not a network shared folder, or samba, or ...) ? have you ever experienced similar weirdness when using git from the command line ?

Comment: @LeGEC I'm running a Macbook Air (Mojave). I'll check if my command line or standalone GIT client (Sourcetree) shows the missing changes. Naturally I cannot reproduce the issue right now! :)

Comment: also worth testing : the "Source control" tab has a "refresh" button (top, buttons to the right of the title "SOURCE CONTROL: GIT"). If you find yourself with vs code not showing the changes you expect, do check if "refresh" displays them correctly.

Comment: I reproduced it this morning. Command-line 'git status' shows my working differences, my Sourcetree GIT client shows them, but VSC does not. The Source Control refresh button didn't help.

Comment: Odd, after I came back from a meeting a 1/2 hour later the changes WERE being reflected, as were new changes. It just stops tracking for a while then starts again, seemingly at random.